# Google FInance Code Throwing Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, spyder

I am trying the sample code from here.

http://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html#remote-data-google

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 27)

f = web.DataReader("F", 'google', start, end)
f.ix['2010-01-04']
```

I am getting this error:

`RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=F&startdate=Jan+01%2C+2010&enddate=Jan+27%2C+2013&output=csv`

Does anyone here have any idea what could be wrong?  I am using Spyder 3.2.4.

Comment: That URL is dead. I've never queried it before and still get the error message. I guess they shut it down.

Comment: did you try the url with a browser?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like google doesn't want you to do that:

http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=F&startdate=Jan+01%2C+2010&enddate=Jan+27%2C+2013&output=csv

> We're sorry... ... but your computer or network may be sending
>   automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request
>   right now.
>
> See Google Help for more information.

Comment: Ahhh.  As I know, Yahoo depreciated all it's finance stuff back in May of last year.  Where do people go for free historical stock data these days?

Comment: you can fetch historical data from yahoo by wrapping the html response directly.. this is the way i do it. Otherwise you have to pay for the data

Comment: Stephan, how do you do that, exactly?  Can you please post some sample code?  Thanks.